# Verify that there are 2 similar names have been entered?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is my program but i want if the user enters a name that the program will first see if that name is not being saved already in the array.This is what i tried,i tried to use contains.but it failed,It doesn't give any errors.
Can you please give me a easy solution if not then say what that code means(i'm just a beginner).

```
   {
        string naam;           
        Console.Write("geef je naam: ");
         naam = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        string[] array = new string[] {naam};

        while (naam != "")
        {
            Console.Write("geef je naam: ");
            naam = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
           //array[naam.Length] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        }
        if (array.Contains(naam))
        {
            Console.Write("naam is al toegevoegd");
        }

        while (naam == " ")
        { 
            break;
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This is the question of the exercise that I do: you write a program that requests the names of friends.

Every time a friend is added checks to see if the name of the friend. If not, then stop the repetition of friends.

Also keeps track of how much the cost for the party be if all those friends.

The price of the Party = 10 € per friend.

Extension: If a friend's name already exists in the array, that name is not added for the second time.

Comment: Okay, so you have some code and a goal. How does it not accomplish what you ask? Does it give an error? You need to be specific in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use a data structure like a `Hashset<string>` for this.  Hashsets have an O(1) lookup as supposed to O(n) by iterating a list.

You might want to normalise the name before putting it in the hashset (if you don't want it case sensitive for example and to remove double spacing etc).

```
var names = new HashSet<string>();
names.Add(NormaliseName("Tom"));
names.Add(NormaliseName("Peter"));
names.Add(NormaliseName("John"));

var normalisedTestName = NormaliseName("Tony");
if (names.Contains(normalisedTestName ))
{
    // Already exists
}
else
{
    // Doesn't exist, add to hashset
    names.Add(normalisedTestName);
}

private static string NormaliseName(string name){
    return name.ToLower().Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this with a list of string and then, you can use linQ to search in your list :

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();

if (names.Any(x => x.Contains(naam))
// stuff
else
names.Add(naam);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var namen = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
bool gedaan = false;

while (!gedaan)
{
    Console.Write("geef je naam: ");
    var naam = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
    gedaan = naam == "";

    if (!gedaan)
    {
        if (!namen.Add(naam))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("naam is al toegevoegd");
        }
    }
};

Console.WriteLine($"totale party kosten: {namen.Count * 10} euro");

Console.ReadLine();
```